# anonymous user cannot access conditional fields

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

On user registration, I want to show a field on "Yes" choice of a radio button. This working fine when I'm logged in as admin. But anonymous user cannot see that field. When I saw the source code of the page, there wasn't any conditional field related js. From permissions, there's only one permission for conditional field "admin conditional field" and even after enabling that permission to anonymous user, still cannot see that field.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen the module, but I will recommend using custom module and javascript in that for such small requirement.